# Does the order of index_together matter in a Django model?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, postgresql

When defining a model with an index_together Meta property, does the order of the columns matter?

In other words, is there a difference between

```
Class myModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    favorite_color = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        index_together = ('name', 'address', 'favorite_color')
```

vs

```
Class myModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    favorite_color = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        index_together = ('favorite_color', 'name', 'address')
```

I only ask because I've noticed when looking at the structure of a table, each column in the key has an "index in key" property. Does MySQL/PostgreSQL expect the columns to be queried in that order?

Just as an aside, is there a great deal of difference between indexing the columns together vs separately?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The order of index_together explains the "path" the index is created.
You can query from left to the right to profit from the index.

So with your first `index_together`:

```
    index_together = ('name', 'address', 'favorite_color')
```

if your first filter is `name` the index is used. If the first is `name` and the second is `address` the index is used, too.

But if you filter by `address` and then `name` or `address`, `favorite_color` the index can't be used.

Comment: Would the index still have a way of being used with a ManyToMany relationship? Let's say `Recipe` is ManyToMany with `Ingredients`, and ingredients has an index on `('type', 'flavor')` or something. If I have an instance of `recipe`, would something like `recipe.ingredient_set.filter(type='cheese', flavor='mozzarella')` use the index? What if the index was instead `('recipe', 'type', 'flavor')`? Thanks again!

Comment: That "what if the index was instead" should be `('id', 'type', 'flavor')`. My bad.

Comment: @omeinusch it seems that the right way to answer this question is to state how the index_together statement maps to a CREATE INDEX statement with a migration, either with South or Django 1.7+  -- do you know this?

Comment: @MarkChackerian If you have another question, feel free to ask. But I think, comments aren't the right place. If you know the answer, feel free to edit. In time of the question, Django 1.7 wasn't published.

Comment: I dug into the Django source code to answer my own follow up question and confirmed that Django does the right thing -- the order of the columns in the generated CREATE INDEX statement is in the same order as the fields listed in the index_together declaration -- see https://github.com/Architizer/application/commit/d24b8a772b239e26ba7b663dd3d3de88e1b29f9a & https://github.com/django/django/blob/26996e2d55719deb0a0b85c642c88658c929106c/django/db/backends/base/schema.py#L851